# Auto Increment Growing Faster than Number of Rows?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowpipe that is copying a CSV into a staging table. On a routine, I run a merge command and remove rows from the staging table from staging. To ensure that I only remove rows that have been processed, and not rows that have been inserted since the merge process began, I and only merging rows that are `<=` the current maximum ingest row number. Once I have processed those rows, I delete rows from the staging table that are against `<=` that number.

My ingest table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingest_staging (
    collapse_key VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    target VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    action VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    params OBJECT NOT NULL,
    ingest_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    ingest_row BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1
);
```

I noticed that while I was running the copy and merge routine, not all rows that were inserted into the staging table got merged into the production table, yet all rows were deleted. I disabled the merge process and just ran the copy process on a newly created ingest table (to clear the auto increment field) and immediately noticed the table count was out of sync with the autoicrement field:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "count", MAX(INGEST_ROW) as "max_ingest_row" FROM ingest_staging;
```

The first batch of rows copied in showed a 28k discrepancy between the two.

```
count: 368640, max_ingest_row: 397312
    COUNT AND INGEST OUT OF SYNC: 28672
```

And after 15 minutes there was a discrepancy of 3.3mm between the number of rows and the autoincrement field.

```
count: 15624757, max_ingest_row: 18953955
    COUNT AND INGEST OUT OF SYNC: 3329198
```

The count matches exactly the number of source rows I'm copying from, so I know no rows got dropped.

My guess is that, while the number auto increments, it's not guaranteed that a lower auto increment number will get inserted at a later time. Is this what is happening?

Why is the autoincrement column out of sync with the number of rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake leverages SEQUENCES for autoincrement columns and does not guarantee a "gapless" increment of numbers in that sequence. Snowflake guarantees that the numbers are sequential and unique, but not necessarily gap-free.

Take a look here in the documentation if you are interested:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#sequence-semantics

Comment: Thanks I was just about to answer with the same thing. It also doesn't guarantee the sequence will be inserted in order. So you may insert rows 5, 10, 7 in that order. I believe I have managed to solve my ingest problem using Time Travel. I store the current time before I apply the merge, then apply everything in staging, then delete everything from staging that can be found at the snapshot at that stored time. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/at-before.html

Comment: If the order matters, you may also want to look into loading the `metadata$file_row_number` value in your `COPY INTO` statement and leverage that for your order.  Not sure if it matters to you, but that will retain the order the records are in the file.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that. It's a constant stream throughout the day of hundreds of files- often concurrently. So the rows within any one file aren't that important